# How to process the files in hdfs using python

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

Can some one tell me how can I open and process the files in hdfs inside a python program ?

Thanks

Comment: What does "process" mean?

Comment: @Kevin To work with file. I need to run the script on the file (inside a python program)

Comment: @Kevin Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28139406/reading-writing-files-from-hdfs-using-python-gives-error  I am trying to achieve it using python

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of thees:

https://code.google.com/p/libpyhdfs/

https://github.com/traviscrawford/python-hdfs

or just do something like that without external libs:

```
file = subprocess.Popen(["hadoop", "fs", "-cat", "/path/to/file"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in file.stdout:
    print line
```

Comment: Can I use this to store the output file on hdfs as well ?

Comment: I tried this but getting error. It is not able to open the file. My file name is "sample.txt". My hadoop is in /usr/bin/hadoop  So do I need to give the path as " /usr/bin/hadoop/sample.txt" ?? Or Am I wrong ??

Comment: I tried you method Popen but not wroking as expected :

Comment: I have added the problem in separate thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28139406/reading-writing-files-from-hdfs-using-python-gives-error                                                                               Please let me know I am doing wrong here